# How can I deploy the same resource files to the 14 hive and global resource folder?

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, resources, localization

I currently have a SharePoint 2010 project which I created an empty element within and created my various resource files. I have set these resources to be deployed as type AppGlobalResource.

This works fine and allows me to access my resource values

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyResources, MyLabel %>" />
```

The next thing I want to be able to do is access the resource values from the code behind. So [I read](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/sharepoint-global-resource-resx-file-locations/) that to access the values I should use SPUtility.GetLocalizedString.

So I created a helper class like below.

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{

        public static string GetResourceValue(string resource)
        {
            var lang = SPContext.Current.Web != null ? SPContext.Current.Web.Language : 1033;
            string result = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:" + resource,"RegistrationResource",lang);

            return result;
        }

}
```

To access the values using this approach I need to allow deploy my resource files to the hive, which is straightforward enough. Add a mapped SharePoint folder and add the files into there. But the problem is I now have two versions of the files in the same project. So I tried adding the resource files using the *Add Existing* and then *Link To* option but it doesn't seem to let you do this.

What is the best way of deploying to the hive and to the Global_ResourceFolder using a SharePoint Feature / Package without having multiple copies of resource files?

**EDIT:**
I have edited the Package.Template.xml file which successfully deploys the file to the hive. But not in the Resources folder. If I amend the location below to use Resources\ or even Resources/ it gives an error saying

> Error 1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error:
>   Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file:

Resources\RegistrationResource.resx
        0   0   Company.Sharepoint.Resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <RootFiles>
    <RootFile Location="RegistrationResource.resx" />
  </RootFiles>
</Solution>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I have gone with is as follows:

1. Create a new SharePoint 2010 project
2. Create an empty SharePoint Element
3. Add the resource files to the element
4. Set the file's property 'Deployment Type' to AppGlobalResource and clear the deployment 'path' to be blank
5. Add a SharePoint 2010 mapped folder and map it to the Resources folder in the 14 hive
6. Copy the resource files from the Element to the Resources folder (don't worry this doesn't need to be maintained
7. Create an XCOPY command that runs on pre-build to copy the resource from the Element to the mapped folder (example below)

   xcopy "$(ProjectDir)GlobalResources\MyResource.resx" "$(ProjectDir)Resources\" /Y /R

Hope this helps someone else, please let me know if anyone has a better approach!

Answer (score 0):

Andi,

Best way to deploy resource file in Application Directories's App_GlobalResources folder.

For this deployment follow below steps in VS2010.

1. Add one SharePoint Elements in VS2010 Project.
2. Add Resource file in this Element folder.
3. Select the Resource file's property and see the "Deployment Type" property and change it to -> "AppGlobalResource"

Then deploy your project in which you want to deploy resource file.

Happy Deploying...!!!

Comment: I have already said I have done this, the issue is also deploying the same file to the 14 hive. Any ideas?